# Вывод прочтённого из сокета при достижении символа новой строки

Tags: c#, сокет

Не могу получить ответ от сервера сокета для клиента на С#. После вызова `Receive` происходит блокировка и не снимается, даже если я превышу количество символов предназначенные для чтения.

Есть аналог кода на php, он работает и ответ получает. Ответ - произвольная строка заканчивающаяся символом новой строки. В php для этого нужно в функции [socket_read](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-read.php) третьим параметром указать `PHP_NORMAL_READ`.

Возможно ли в C# настроить снятие блокировки и вывод полученного ответа, когда строка ответ достигает новой строки?

Или я просто где-то ошибся?

Вот клиент приложение на C#

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleSocketClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SocketReader("127.0.0.1", 10000);
        }

        static void SocketReader(string address, int port)
        {
            var ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port);
            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(ipPoint);
            socket.Send(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("READER"));

            do {
                Console.WriteLine("loop");
                var data = new byte[2048];
                Console.WriteLine("start receive");
                var bytes = socket.Receive(data, data.Length, 0);
                Console.WriteLine("end receive");
                Console.WriteLine(bytes);
            }
            while (socket.Available > 0);

            socket.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Ответ

```
loop
start receive
```

**Дополнительный вопрос**

Может он блокируется до того момента, пока не разорвется соединение?

Comment: [If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is available](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receive?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @tym32167 Ничего не понятно. Данные отправляются, но в момент отправки C#-клиенту происходит блокировка. Если я отправляю PHP-клиенту всё нормально.

Comment: Не знаю что и как у вас отправляется, но блокировка означает, что данные не приехали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Причина была в неправильном перекодировании. Изменил `Encoding.Unicode` на `Encoding.UTF8` и всё стало работать по часам.